# What is Trojan-QT5? How to check home brew history?

Tags: security, homebrew

Just concerned after brew deleted this casks `trojan-qt5` when installing angular CLI `brew install nginx`.

I use OSX and I try to be very careful when download stuff. How can I check further information on it?

How to check how it was installed in the first place?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information about what this project used to do, and review its code, from its original GitHub page: https://github.com/charlieethan/Trojan-Qt5

Trojan-QT5 was based off of Shadowsocks QT, which seems to be about encrypting traffic. A white paper on that can be viewed here: https://shadowsocks.org/assets/whitepaper.pdf

Shadowsocks was a VPN alternative primarily used in China to get past the firewall.